# How do I add a search box to our website?

Tags: search

When I read the help section, it tells me where to go, but it says I don't have access.  I just want a search box on our site.

Comment: Could you clarify yourself a bit? What help section did you read? Which CMS are you using? Which CiviCRM version are you using? (From only looking at your question I can not even find out IF you are using CiviCRM) What kind of search box do you mean?

Comment: if you could paste in some of the links you are trying it might help shed light

Comment: As mentioned by others, further clarification on your question would help allow people to answer it.

Answer (score 1):

Discuss this with OneEach Technologies (your hosting partner/provider). You likely don't have permissions needed to make the changes you want without their support.